# LMR16030 only works when input <35V, explodes or burn if more

Tags: power-supply, power, switching-regulator

I'm designing an switching power supply that requires to have multiple sources of voltage.

When the LMR16030 is on Lifepo4 24V battery pack, it runs perfectly fine and provides accurate voltages for extended periods of time (several days running).

I have an input switcher relay that switches both ground and main source of my circuit, from 20-30VDC on the battery to 48VDC when my system is plugged. This input switcher is a basic 2P relay that switches as hotplug system.

When I switch between two sources of less than 35V, there is absolutely no problem at all, I can switch all day long and it runs fine.

If I crank up the voltage to more than 35V, the LMR16030 literally either burns or even blows up some time, with cracked case and missing pieces.

I have checked on oscilloscope for voltage spikes, even added voltage ramp circuit, but nothing has changed between two prototypes.

Specs:

20-30VIN on Batt, 48VIN on rail
18VOUT 2.5A, including several other switching supplies providing different voltages to MCUs, SBCs, and a bunch of 3.3V-5V-12V peripherals

BOM:

Inductor: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Power-Inductors_Sumida-CDRH104RNP-180NC_C225049.html

Diode: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Schottky-Barrier-Diodes-SBD_GOODWORK-SS810_C2922188.html

The rest is standard stuff found on LCSC.

Placement and routing as below (I have tried other configurations, same behaviour):

Schematics and routing below:
[image: Copper]

[image: Routing]

[image: Schemes]

Comment: Is the inductor saturating?

Comment: Inductor is 18uH 3.5A sat current, my load is about 2.5A@18V, I don't think it's that. 

Maybe not enough inductance ? Yet I used Powerbench.

Comment: Post a schematic; the one you implemented with the values you used and with a data sheet link to the inductor. Add details about switching frequency and load current range. Also post an image of the PCB copper you designed for it.

Comment: Done, hope it will be useful !

Comment: What's the part number for C3? Also, could you try adding a 3.3µF capacitor (same type as C3) between the output and ground directly to the side of L3? You can scrape off some solder mask to bodge it onto the existing PCB. Trace length matters with switching converters.

Comment: C3 is this one: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Multilayer-Ceramic-Capacitors-MLCC-SMD-SMT_TDK-C2012X5R1H335KT000N_C342775.html

As for output capacitor, there also is a huge capa bank (about 30000uF) besides this regulator, but I tried with and without it, and it doesn't change anything to its behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say what is causing your issues from afar. However, your PCB layout needs help.

PCB layout recommendation is on page 26 of the data sheet for the LMR16030.
"[LMR16030PEVM User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/snvu496)" also has a sample schematic and layout for operation at 500 kHz.
It's a really good idea to follow these recommendations as the product engineers have spent considerable time to get the layout right.

Your layout is sub-par for a 540 kHz switching power supply for the following reasons:

- This issue could be responsible for voltage spikes on the input to the IC which can be damaging. C3 ground connection isn't a least path connection from pin-2 to the ground paddle. You have a thermal on the ground side of C3's pad (flood the pad) and the ground path to the paddle goes to a ground plane and back up to the paddle through vias. I have seen switching power supplies fail to operate properly due to sloppy wiring like this. **Ground connections need to be on the top layer** for the high current switching paths. This is clearly done in the user's guide and in the data sheet examples. Small amounts of inductance in the wrong place will mess up switchers.
- C3 value is probably too high. Follow the recommendations in the user's guide. You need a small valued capacitor close to the IC. Smaller valued capacitors have a higher resonant frequency. The 3.3 uF capacitor can be mounted slightly farther away as the frequency response of this bulk capacitance is less critical.
- You need a small capacitor just to the right of the inductor. The 3.3 uF capacitor is probably suitable for this part. Again, follow the user's guide recommendations on placement. The 30 mF capacitor bank elsewhere on the output is too far away to do any good for high frequency currents, plus, the inductance on the 30 mF capacitor bank is too high to do anything with the fast rising edges.
- Beware of ceramic capacitor types. High-K ceramic capacitance values can change considerably with voltage. If you can, stick with X7R, or something close to X7R.

Comment: To add to your last point: According to the characterization sheet for the 3.3µF capacitor, it has about 400nF left at 48V. And even worse, its resonant frequency is just barely above 1MHz. It's pretty awful. https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/capacitor/ceramic/mlcc/charasheet/c2012x5r1h335k125ab.pdf

Comment: I don't mind the ground path: inner layer plane (with multiple vias) is as low, or maybe slightly lower, than an all-top-side route would be. SRF is not important as that simply means it's at its lowest impedance, it's doing as good a job as possible. More likely the C(V) reduction, and input transient, are the culprit.

Comment: Note that placing multiple capacitors in parallel may invite resonances. Mind the trace and body length; figure 0.5 to 1 nH per mm of length, and keep R > sqrt(L/C) in the loop between capacitors. Usually this means the larger capacitor will be given ESR, usually by choosing an electrolytic.  This applies to the output side as well, which is generally preferred to have a local bypass (it isn't *required*, it could do without; but reasons such as stability, local noise impact, and emissions, generally prefer one).

Comment: Alright, thanks for all those elements, very enlightening. 

I am no electronics expert, only self-taught, and I didn't know for instance that capacitors had derating curves...

I will try and implement all the answers you gave and come back to you soon, thanks again.

Comment: It would indeed seem like C3 input capacitor is at fault. I changed it for a 1uF 100V I had in stock and now it accepts up to 48V input without burning when unloaded and about 46V input when loaded, but burns at 48V… I will keep on investigating this matter but we’re on the right path ! Thanks again